# Clozure CL on Mac OS X: get rid of the GUI?

Tags: macos, common-lisp, ccl

I want to run a CCL REPL from a command line. What should I do to prevent CCL from starting that GUI thing (the menu and the listener window)? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homebrew has a recipe for Clozure CL, and will set up everything like you'd expect.

`$ brew install clozure-cl`

Now type `ccl` or `ccl64` at the command line.

Comment: brew doesn't find 'clozure-cl'. Is it removed from repo?

Comment: Yes, it appears so. You can install a local recipe from the archived, original formula, or better yet, become the new maintainer. https://github.com/jf/homebrew/blob/59a02849a75ffede091ef97448350bbfb98558ea/Library/Formula/clozure-cl.rb

Comment: I'd like to try maintaining. How can I become a homebrew ccl maintainer?

Answer (score 4):

After I dug around in `Applications/CCL`, I found this:

```
username@computer:/Applications/CCL
$ ./dx86cl64 
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.7  (DarwinX8664)!
?
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help -- the listener window still pops up

Comment: @MikeIvanov: Not for me? :-)  I didn't install from the App Store.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution.

Originally I installed CCL the "Mac way" - from the App Store (silly me). Regardless of how I called dx86cl64 it always opened a listener window.

I removed the app, downloaded ftp://clozure.com/pub/release/1.7/ccl-1.7-darwinx86.tar.gz and unpacked it under /opt/ccl-1.7. Then I created ~/bin/ccl with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "/opt/ccl-1.7/dx86cl64" -K utf-8 $*
```

Problem solved.